# How to update a field of struct saved in a file?

Tags: c, struct, file-handling

I made a structure as follows :

```
struct record {
char name[20];
int age;
};
```

and saved in the file , say "record.dat" with the help of fwrite and can read with fread.
I want to modify/update the age of certain name in the file and can't seem to update that certain age.
Any help/hint would be appreciated

```
fread(&struct_name,sizeof(struct record),1,fp);
struct_name.age = xx;
```

only update the local variable and doesn't actually modify the content of the file ...

Comment: Do you write changes back to file? Please create [mcve] to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: You have to again write it to the file using `fwrite`, then only the file will be updated.

Comment: Writing again with fwrite adds another structure... It remains as it is...

Comment: I think the question is complete.. You just have to modify field of struct that is saved in a certain file and modify the saved file as well....

Comment: You need to call set the file pointer to where it was before calling `fread` (see [`fgetpos`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetpos/), or [`ftell`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/)), then set it to that position before calling `fwrite` (see [`fseek`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/)). Without writing the changes back to the file, the content of the file won't change magically.

Comment: Doesn't doing that just add another structure instead of overwriting?

Comment: I agree with the @user3121023 . You can't modify struct in a variable and in a file in single shot. You have to write it back to the file by yourself. Or more precisely overwrite the existing record in the file.

Comment: @Itachi.tilak no, provided you use `ftell` and `fseek`. Click on the links provided in the previous comments

Comment: Now I get it.. I will try.. I knew about fseek and ftell but didn't expect to just overwrite